# Change the baselinestretch (line spacing) only for figure captions

Tags: captions, line-spacing

I use

```
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
```

in my preamble to change line spacing of my main text. For my Figure cpations I'd like to have a value of `1.0` or `1.2`. Is there an easy way to change the line-spacing for figure captions, table captions,... independently?

Comment: Use the `setspace` package that already takes care of that.

Comment: So, how can I change the spacing for captions? I only found out, how I can change the spacing of the main text. This does not affect the spacing of captions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `caption` package together with `setspace` package. This is what `caption` documentation says:

[image]

Further, you can use `setspace` package to adjust spacing for the whole document by using the commands it provides as noted by egreg.

A MWE will be:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,kantlipsum,setspace}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font={stretch=1.2}}     %% change 1.2 as you like
\captionsetup[figure]{font={stretch=1.2}}    %% change 1.2 as you like
 %% or
 %% \captionsetup{font={stretch=1.2}}  %% this affects both figure and table


%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\setstretch{1.5}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Some chapter}
\kant[1-3]
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{\kant[1]}\label{tab:mytable}
Some table comes here
\end{table}

\kant[4-8]
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{\kant[2]}\label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For anyone else who's confused, its `font=onehalfspacing`, not `font=onehalf-spacing`