# Customizing line spacing in ctex classes

Tags: line-spacing, ctex

### My goal

I recently started using the `ctex` classes to convert some of my English articles into Chinese. Regarding the line spacing, I would like to achieve the following:

1. The body text should have a [leading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading) 150% of the font size.

   - Here, leading refers to as the distance between two consecutive Latin baselines, which equals the distance between two consecutive ideographic baselines of the CJK characters. On the other hand, the em-box has a size given by the font size.
2. So should the captions of tables and figures (in case there is a very long caption).
3. And, of course, the footnotes, quotes, quotations, etc., as well.
4. However, I do *not* want the rows of my tables to be stretched, since usually Chinese only appears in the header and the table contents are just numbers.

   - I can use `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{<factor>}%` for stretching.
5. I also want to avoid stretching the vertical skips around displayed math.
6. **Added** (June 4, 2018): Since math formulae are mostly in Latin/Greek, the leading for them should obey the English typesetting rules, i.e., 120%.

### My question

How can I achieve the above descriptions? I would appreciate a solution which allows me to set the line spacing of body text, captions, footnotes, etc., *separately*.

### Why would I want this?

Unlike English typesetting, where [a leading 120–145% of the font size](https://practicaltypography.com/line-spacing.html) is recommended, Chinese (or Japanese, Korean) often requires a leading 150–180% of the font size. This is because CJK glyphs have much less [side-bearings](https://ilovetypography.com/typography-terms/typography-terms-s/) compared to their Latin counterparts, and need more space to breathe (except for newspapers where the recommendation is 125–133% for Chinese).

This is *fundamentally* different from an [ugly university-style requirement](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133032/164314). A normal Chinese footnote *should* have slightly larger leading than just 120% of font size.

Also, note how I have avoided using terms like `single spacing`, `1.5 spacing`, etc. I think professionals use point size for leading, or at least use its ratio to the font size, rather than some obscure `<multiple> spacing`.

---

### Attempt 1

First, I tried `\linespread{1.25}\selectfont`:

- According to Code Line 3747 of the `ctex` documentation: `{ \dim_to_decimal:n { (#2) * \c_six / \c_five } }`, the initial leading is set at 120% of *every* corresponding font size. And, 150% divided by 120% is `1.25`.

But this spreads *everything*!

Same with the `leading` package: It just saves me from doing calculations. In a `\documentclass[zihao=-4]{ctexart}` document, the `\normalsize` command sets font size at `12bp`, so I can issue `\leading{18bp}`. But since `\leading` uses `\linespread` internally, this also spreads everything.

---

### Attempt 2

Then, I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153366/164314) suggesting a combination of the `setspace` and `caption` packages:

```
% Preamble
%\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace} % In my case
\setstretch{1.25} % 1.5/1.2 = 1.25
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font={stretch=1.25}}
```

which covers my goals 1, 2, 4 and 5. For footnotes, I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227065/164314) where

```
% Preamble
\let\oldfootnote\footnote
%\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\oldfootnote{\onehalfspacing #1}}
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\oldfootnote{\setstretch{1.25} #1}} % In my case
```

was suggested by the OP. This works fine until there is a second footnote on the same page. The two blocks of footnotes will have an inconsistent separation. I think I also have to adjust `\footnotesep` to get uniform spacing in footnotes, but by how much?

- According to Code Line 3905 of the `ctex` doc­u­menta­tion: `\dim_set:Nn \footnotesep { \dim_use:N \box_ht:N \strutbox }` and the fact that `\strutbox` has a default height of `.7\baselineskip`. I guess `\setlength{\footnotesep}{.875\baselineskip}` will do the job?
- **Edited** (June 2, 2018): Apparently something else is at work when setting the footnote separation. See the two different MWE’s below.

---

### Minimal working examples

**Edited** (June 2, 2018): I was too naive to assume the same typesetting output for English and Chinese inputs. The following English/Latin MWE illustrates that `\footnotesep` needs to be *increased*:

```
\documentclass[zihao=-4,scheme=plain]{ctexart} % Do not use Chinese headings
\usepackage{blindtext} % Use Latin blind text, in case you don't have Chinese font.
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand*{\bodytextlinespread}{1.25} % 1.5/1.2 = 1.25
\newcommand*{\captionlinespread} {1.25} % 1.5/1.2 = 1.25
\newcommand*{\footnotelinespread}{1.25} % 1.5/1.2 = 1.25
% Set body text line spacing without stretching displayed math.
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{\bodytextlinespread}
% Patch caption line spacing.
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font={stretch=\captionlinespread}}
% Patch footnote line spacing.
\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{%
  \oldfootnote{\setstretch{\footnotelinespread} #1}}
  % The mistakenly added space before #1 should have been dropped.
\begin{document}
\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}
\[
e^{i \pi} + 1 = 0.
\]
Aha! Another footnote\footnote{\blindtext}.
\begin{table}[h]
\caption[Short caption]{A table with a really really really really
 really really really really really really really really really 
 really really really long caption.}
\centering%
\begin{tabular}{c c}
\toprule
Chinese & Word \\
\midrule
  $10$  & $20$ \\
  $10$  & $20$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\blindtext
\begin{quote}
\blindtext
\end{quote}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

But a Chinese MWE suggests that `\footnotesep` should be *decreased* (the difference is subtle, but visible):

```
\documentclass[zihao=-4]{ctexart} % Use Chinese headings
\usepackage{zhlipsum} % Use Chinese dummy text.
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand*{\bodytextlinespread}{1.25} % 1.5/1.2 = 1.25
\newcommand*{\captionlinespread} {1.25} % 1.5/1.2 = 1.25
\newcommand*{\footnotelinespread}{1.25} % 1.5/1.2 = 1.25
% Set body text line spacing without stretching displayed math.
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{\bodytextlinespread}
% Patch caption line spacing.
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font={stretch=\captionlinespread}}
% Patch footnote line spacing.
\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{%
  \oldfootnote{\setstretch{\footnotelinespread} #1}}
  % The mistakenly added space before #1 should have been dropped.
\begin{document}
\zhlipsum*[1]\footnote{\zhlipsum*[2]}
\[
e^{i \pi} + 1 = 0.
\]
Aha! Another footnote\footnote{\zhlipsum*[3]}. \zhlipsum*[4]
\begin{table}[h]
\caption[Short caption]{A table with a really really really really
 really really really really really really really really really 
 really really really long caption.}
\centering%
\begin{tabular}{c c}
\toprule
Chinese & Word \\
\midrule
  $10$  & $20$ \\
  $10$  & $20$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\zhlipsum*[5]
\begin{quote}
\zhlipsum*[6]
\end{quote}
\zhlipsum*[7]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Skillmon MWE added.

Comment: The `\footnotesep` should work if you just put `\footnotesep=1.25\footnotesep` at the end of your preamble. Also you have a white space too much in your `\footnote`. It should be `\renewcommand\footnote[1]{\oldfootnote{\setstretch{1.25}#1}}`. And perhaps you want to include `\usepackage{etoolbox}\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\setstretch{1}}` if you have `tabular`s outside of `table` environments which shouldn't get stretched, too.

Comment: And in case you need to use `\footnotetext` somewhere, you should redefine that one, too, with `\let\oldfootnotetext\footnotetext\renewcommand\footnotetext[1]{\oldfootnotetext{\setstretch{1}#1}}`

Comment: @Skillmon Thank you for your comments. Since `1.25` appears a lot, I decide to wrap it in three separate commands (for customizing). However, I was too naive to assume that English and Chinese inputs produce the same footnote separation. Please take a look at the updated MWE’s (the second one, in particular).

Comment: I think your second MWE looks good (except the space in `\footnote`). What is still bothering you?

Comment: @Skillmon You’re right: The 2nd MWE _looks_ good. However, when issued `\the\ccwd` (width of em-box), `\the\baselineskip` and `\the\ht\strutbox` in footnote, I got `9.03374pt`, `13.5506pt` and `9.48537pt` in **both** MWE’s, which are expected (`\footnotesize` is `9bp` in `zihao=-4` ctex classes; leading is `1.5` of `9bp`; height of `\strutbox` is `.7*1.5` of `9bp`). But `\the\footnotesep` in the 1st MWE yields `8.4pt` (`.7` of footnote leading in `12pt` standard `article`), while in the 2nd `9.8648pt`. This deviation is caused by class option `scheme=plain` and neither equals `9.48537pt`.

Comment: @Skillmon BTW, the slightly larger `9.8648pt` comes from the class default option `linespread=1.3` (`.7*1.2*1.3` of `9bp`). It appears that `\setlength\footnotesep{\ht\strutbox}` need be issued _somewhere_, which should be a global update and should utilize `\footnotelinespread`.

Comment: If it globally looks good, there is no need to adjust anything, imho, even if the values seem strange, the looks of it say everything's fine.